# Joomla login component with JFactory::getUser

Tags: joomla, components

I have component that have his own table with users and when user login, JFactory::getUser didn't work. How Joomla can understand that user is login? in my model it is $this->setStatus('loggedIn',true); Can someone just help me with direction, what I need to write when user login

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, what are you trying to achieve? Can you show some code to (a single line doesn't help us).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id){
    //User is logged in
}
else{
   //User not logged in
}
```

If that is what you are asking. If not, please provide more info

Comment: $user =& JFactory::getUser(); didn't help because users for frontend are in other table.